# How to use canvas.drawPicture() properly Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-canvas

I was unable to find a workable example of how to use `canvas.drawPicture()` when searching. This implementation comes from my understanding of the Android docs, although there's very little info there.

This is my current onDraw() implementation:

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Picture p = new Picture();
    Canvas pCanvas = p.beginRecording(200,200);
    TextPaint tPaint = new TextPaint();
    pCanvas.drawText("Hello!",0,0,tPaint);
    p.endRecording();

    //now draw the picture
    canvas.drawPicture(p);

}
```

Nothing shows up on the screen.

I understand this example is pretty useless. Ideally I would be drawing to the Picture in the background and passing that to the onDraw() method, but this is just a start to see if I understand how it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Nothing shows up in the screen. Why?

The reason for this is your `View` is `Hardware accelerated`. You need to have a software canvas for this to work. How do you do that? Add the below line of code to the constructors of your `View`.

```
 setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE,null);
```

Now it would work. Also in your `drawText` the coordinates are `(0,0)`. The text is drawn from the baseline, and screen starts at `(0,0)`. So you might want to try something like `(0,50)`, or so to render the full text on the screen.

**MORE INFO:**
You can draw a picture to `Canvas` via two methods. `Canvas.drawPicture()` or `Picture.draw()`. It's important to note that in both the cases you need a Software canvas. If you try `Picture.draw(canvas)` and pass in a hardware accelerated canvas, you will get the below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Picture playback is only supported on software canvas.
```

However, if you make the `Canvas.drawPicture()` on a hardware accelerated canvas, nothing happens. The picture is never drawn.

*API23 however removes this restrictions and allows to draw on Hardware accelerated canvas*